# Dropdownlist to label output C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, visual-web-developer

I want to show different labels output from DropDownList with button

```
select Item on DropDownList and click button to show output in label
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lable1.Text=DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

or u can do

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       String input=DropDownList1.SelectedIndex >= 0 ? DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() : "";
       lable1.Text=input;
   }
```

Comment: if it work mark as ur answer. So that it is useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just write down this in `button click event`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    label.text = ComboBox.SelectedText;
}
```

Comment: 'You can use the SelectedText property to retrieve or change the currently selected text in a ComboBox control. However, you should be aware that the selection can change automatically because of user interaction. For example, if you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.'. Also, OP has asked for this to work with a DropDownList, not a ComboBox control...